# Message is not send via a chat application Java

Tags: sockets

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, the message is not sent actually and it's not displayed in the message area. I can't figure it out. Maybe someone can help me.
The code is compiled but i'm not receiving an error. The program simply don't work. What can i do to make it work and improve the quality of GUI (make it store what we write) ?

Server:

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ionutserver;

import static java.awt.SystemColor.text;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

/**
 *
 * @author Ionutz
 */
public class IonutServer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
        
        
        JTextField areaMessage = new JTextField();
        areaMessage.setBounds(10, 20, 150, 80);
        JTextArea input = new JTextArea();
        input.setBounds(10, 200, 150, 80);
        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setBounds(300, 100 , 100, 30);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Server Ionut");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        panel.add(areaMessage); panel.add(input);
        panel.add(send); frame.add(panel); frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); frame.setSize(600, 400); frame.setVisible(true);
        
     ServerSocket  s = new ServerSocket(100);
   
   Socket s1= s.accept();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     s1.getInputStream()));
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
     s1.getOutputStream()));
        
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == send) {
                    try {
                        bw.write(input.getText());
                        bw.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        });
     
        
    }
    
}
```

And Client :

```html
package ionutclient;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class IonutClient {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BadLocationException {
        
       JTextField areaMessage = new JTextField();
        areaMessage.setBounds(10, 20, 150, 80);
        JTextArea input = new JTextArea();
        input.setBounds(10, 200, 150, 80);
        JButton send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setBounds(300, 100 , 100, 30);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client Ionut");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        panel.add(areaMessage); panel.add(input);
        panel.add(send); frame.add(panel); frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); frame.setSize(600, 400); frame.setVisible(true);
        
  Socket s = new Socket("192.161.0.100",100);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     s.getInputStream()));
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
     s.getOutputStream()));
        
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == send) {
                    try {
                        bw.write(input.getText());
                        bw.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        });
     
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is client socket created properly? is your code entering actionPerformed with right e.getSource() value ? How do you ensure that you are clicking "send" after socket is created?

Comment: Don't know what i'm doing wrong , i did not receive errors....the only problem i have is that the message will not send.

Comment: Can you add debugs at below places? serverSocket.accept(), Socket creation and actionPerformaed event in both classes etc.

Comment: On most platforms binding to a reserved port (any port number less than 1024) is considered privileged and must be performed by root (or the OS equivalent). Are you sure the server socket is getting created properly?

Comment: This is what i'm getting on client side...Socket.<init>(SocketAddress, SocketAddress, boolean) line: not available     Socket.<init>(String, int) line: not available 
ChatClient.main(String[]) line: 35 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source). Maybe i've done some mistake while writing the code

Comment: Can anyone give me a simple example how to make a simple chat ?